# Matplotlib stacked barplot in wrong order

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I am doing a barplot in matplotlib. What I would like to do is put the largest group (orange) on the bottom and the smaller ones on the top. How do I achieve that in Python?

[image]

Comment: Please provide your input data and your code in a reproducible format (see [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the groups are plotted from bottom to top in the order they come in the sequence given to the `hist` function.

So you can order the sequence as you want, in reverse order of the size of each group for example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

vmin, vmax = 0, 10

# By default data is plot in the order given
sizes1 = (10, 50, 100)
data1 = [np.random.randint(vmin, vmax, s) for s in sizes1]
labels1 = [f"Size: {len(x)}" for x in data1]

# You can sort the data the way you want
data2 = sorted(data1, key=lambda x: -len(x))
labels2 = [f"Size: {len(x)}" for x in data2]
sizes2 = tuple(len(x) for x in data2)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

ax1.hist(data1, stacked=True, rwidth=0.5, label=labels1)
ax1.set_title(sizes1)
ax1.legend()

ax2.hist(data2, stacked=True, rwidth=0.5, label=labels2)
ax2.set_title(sizes2)
ax2.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: histograms]

---

**Edit:** with `ax.bar`.

Still the same idea, sort the data adequately and draw in that order, but here you have full responsibility of the drawing order.

So taking the already sorted `data2` we have:

```py
bins = np.arange(vmin, vmax + 1)
x = bins[:-1] + 0.5
ys = [np.histogram(data, bins=bins)[0] for data in data2]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

bottom = np.zeros_like(ys[0])
for y, label in zip(ys, labels2):
    ax.bar(x, y, bottom=bottom, label=label)
    bottom += y

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: bar chart]

Comment: No particular reason, except the absence of reproducible example

Comment: I think the gist of it is that you have control by ordering the data, and I think OP got it since the answer is accepted, but here you go I made an edit.